# Stratification McNemar Test in R

Tags: r, paired-data, stratification, mcnemar-test

I have categorical data before and after a condition (paired data) about preferences (yes/no) and I have other variables such as sociodemographic values (sex, ethnicity, etc).

What I need to know if those preferences have changed before and after a condition and if those other variables like sociodemographic play a role. What I preliminary thought about is a McNemar's Chi-squared test stratified by those sociodemographic variables. Is it correct? and if correct, do you know any R package? Should I think about conditional logistic regression with sociodemographic as weights?

Comment: Are the sociodemographic variables actually discordant between your matched pairs?

Comment: No, the pairs are the same patient before and after so have the same sociodemographic.

Comment: then there's no need to account for them with McNemar or any conditional analysis. In fact, it's downright impossible to do so.

Answer (score 1):

#### Rationale for a paired design

Dependent data actually provide a *superior* design for inferring conditional effects, such as change from baseline. While SES, demographics, etc. comprise the "standard" adjustments for non-conditional analyses, you are at an advantage with the design and model you are considering.

#### Models for dependent data

With clustered data, paired data specifically, variables for adjustment are classified as either within-cluster or between-cluster. Conditional models for paired binary outcomes include **McNemar's Test**, a univariate procedure, and **conditional logistic regression**, the multivariate and imbalanced-cluster analogue. This is a conditional likelihood procedure.

With conditional models, between-cluster confounders -- variables that do not vary within individuals in a cluster -- are handled by "conditioning" and cannot be adjusted for. You can compare this to a paired T-test: since the test simply subtracts the value between pairs, any expected effect of between-cluster variables is subtracted off.

**Mixed-effects logistic regression**, where a random intercept is included for each cluster, is a profile likelihood method and is less efficient and more difficult to fit and interpret. It may be biased too. (I will follow-up this question separately). This is a profile likelihood procedure -- when using most off-the-shelf solvers for these models.

If there is an interest in understanding the *unconditional* effect of these variables, one can present an analysis of "**pairs-as-individuals**" where models for independent data are used in spite of the inherent design. This is a pseudo-likelihood procedure.

#### Testing interaction

A variable is an effect modifier, or a modifier, if the expected difference varies significantly depending on the value of the modifier. If there is an interest in understanding the possible *interaction* between one of the between-cluster variables and the pre-post indicator, you can explore this one of several ways:

1. Adjust for the interaction term in the pairs-as-individuals analysis or in the mixed effects model analysis
2. Fit McNemar's test for each stratum or an appropriate categorization of the modifier, and compare the 1-$\alpha$ confidence intervals for the conditional odds ratio
3. Fit a conditional logistic regression with the pre-post indicator, and the product of the pre-post indicator and the modifier. Note: unlike linear models where one must adjust for the lower level terms, conditional logistic regression handles the lower-level effect of the modifier by conditioning on its outcome.

Typically because post-hoc interaction testing is a sensitivity analysis, and requires a lot of power, and because it's an inverted hypothesis test (the null of no-interaction is a "favorable" outcome for reporting the primary hypothesis), the alpha-level of interaction tests are typically set to 0.1 or even higher depending how imbalanced the modifier term is.