# Mixed effects versus conditional models for paired analyses

Tags: mixed-model, paired-data, clogit

In this CV post I address briefly models for binary dependent data and how they might be used in a paired analysis.
[Stratification McNemar Test in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/518760/stratification-mcnemar-test-in-r/518928#518928)

It occurred to me: I hadn't previously considered using a random effect to handle dependent clusters. Is there a consensus or a rationale to prefer the conditional approach over the random effect? My intuition is that the actual value of the random effect is estimated through a probability model and so it seems like one "spends" more and deals with more assumptions to obtain valid inference.  If so, how do these inefficiencies play out: bias, big SEs, low power?